# Hacer aparecer input(textbox), luego de seleccionar cierto item en un select MVC C#

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net-mvc

Buenas,

La idea es que al seleccionar un item de un select, me aparezca 2 input para el ingreso de información. Mvc no trabaja con runnat="server", ni puedo usar el visible o disable (o por lo menos no lo sé utilizar). Utilizo VS 2013, MVC C#.

De ante mano muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas la intervencion del servidor para activar/desactivar un control de la vista. Utiliza jquery, que se ejecuta en el cliente, para saber cuando el `select` cambio y si tiene el valor que necesitas entonces habilitas los inputs, de lo contrario lo inhabilitas:

```js
$("#mi-select").change(function(){
  if(this.value == 3){ 
    $(".entradas").attr("disabled", false);
  }else{
    $(".entradas").attr("disabled", true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mi-select">
  <option value="1">Opcion 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opcion 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opcion 3 y habilita los inputs</option>
  <option value="4">Opcion 4</option>
 </select>
 
 <div>
  <input type="text" disabled placeholder="input 1" class="entradas" />
  <input type="text" disabled placeholder="input 2" class="entradas" />
 </div>
```

Esto te da la ventaja de que tu pagina no tiene que recargar completamente para activar/desactivar los inputs.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio! me falta estudiar mucho mas jquery